# I am using python: I am getting error while saving a unicode text into '.txt file extenssion

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *
from  tkFileDialog import *
import tkMessageBox
import Tkinter as tk
import Translator
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

app = Tk()
app.title("Eng2Yor (PRONOUN)")
app.geometry("700x500+300+50")

menubar = Menu(app)

#For File Menu
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
def open():
    f = askopenfile(mode= 'r')
    t = f.read()
    text1.delete(0.0, END)
    text1.insert(0.0, t)
filemenu.add_command(label = "Open       Ctrl + O", command = open)
filemenu.add_separator()
def Save():
    name=asksaveasfile(mode='w',defaultextension=".txt")
    text2save=str(text2.get(0.0,END))
    name.write(text2save)
filemenu.add_command(label = "Save", command = Save)
def SaveAs():
    name=asksaveasfile(mode='w',defaultextension=".txt")
    text2save=str(text2.get(0.0,END))
    name.write(text2save)
filemenu.add_command(label = "Save As  Ctrl + S", command = SaveAs)

filemenu.add_separator()
def exit():
    if tkMessageBox.askyesno("Quit", "Do you really want to quit?"):
        app.destroy()
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=exit)

#For View Menu
viewmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
def Translate():
    translate()
viewmenu.add_command(label = "Translate", command = Translate)
def Paste():
    try:
        t = app.selection_get(selection='CLIPBOARD')
        text1.insert(INSERT, t)
    except TclError:
        pass
viewmenu.add_command(label = "Paste", command = Paste)

#For Menus
menubar.add_cascade(label = "File", menu = filemenu)
menubar.add_cascade(label = "Translate", menu = viewmenu)

#For Help Menu
def about():
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("About", "Just an ENGLISH to YORUBA \nPronoun     Translation Machine System \nWhich replaces gender pronouns\nIn yoruba     equivalence")
helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
helpmenu.add_cascade(label = "About", command = about)
def help():
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("About", "It replaces gender pronoun\n'He', 'She'     and 'It'")
helpmenu.add_cascade(label = "Help", command = help)
menubar.add_cascade(label = "Help", menu = helpmenu)

app.config(menu = menubar)

#Toolbar
def translate():
    text2.delete(1.0, END)
    s = text1.get(1.0,END)
    text2.insert(1.0,Translator.translate(s))

def reset():
    text1.delete(1.0, END)
    text2.delete(1.0, END)

toolbar = Frame(app, bg = "#555")
translatebutton = tk.Button(toolbar, font = ('arial black', 12),text =     "Translate", bg = "#266", fg = "#fff", borderwidth=2, relief =     "raised",command=translate)
translatebutton.pack(side="left", expand=1, fill= X)
resetbutton = tk.Button(toolbar, font = ('arial black', 12),text = "Reset",     bg = "#266", fg = "#fff", borderwidth=2, relief = "raised",command=reset)
resetbutton.pack(side="left", expand=1, fill= X)
clossbutton = tk.Button(toolbar, font = ('arial black', 12),text = "Close",     bg = "#266", fg = "#fff", borderwidth=2, relief = "raised",command=exit)
clossbutton.pack(side="left", expand=1, fill= X)
toolbar.pack(side = TOP, fill = X, ipady = 5, ipadx = 15)

#Frames
topFrame = Frame(app, bg = "#bbb", relief=RIDGE)
topFrame.pack(side = TOP, anchor = W, fill = X)
englishtext = Label(topFrame, bg = "#555", font = ('arial black', 12), fg =     "#fff",text="ENGLISH SENTENCE")
englishtext.pack(side="left", expand=1, fill= X)
yorubatext = Label(topFrame, bg = "#555", font = ('arial black', 12), fg =     "#fff",text="YORUBA TRANSLATION")
yorubatext.pack(side="left", expand=1, fill= X)

bottomFrame = Frame(app, relief=FLAT, borderwidth=10, bg = "#000")
bottomFrame.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1, anchor = CENTER)

insideFrame = Frame(bottomFrame, relief=FLAT, borderwidth = 0)
insideFrame.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1, anchor = CENTER)

#Text windows
text1 = Text(insideFrame)
text1.config(font=("consolas", 12), undo=True, wrap='word')
text1.pack(side = LEFT, fill = BOTH, expand = 1)

text2 = Text(insideFrame)
text2.config(font=("consolas", 12), undo=True, wrap='word')
text2.pack(side = LEFT, fill = BOTH, expand = 1)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(text1)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
scrollbar.config(command=text1.yview)
text1.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(text2)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
scrollbar.config(command=text2.yview)
text2.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

app.mainloop()

It gives the following error: messagetext2save=str(text2.get(0.0,END)) UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Please can anyone help me with fixing this code. What i am trying to do here is     that when I enter english text into my application, it will translate it into     another language and when I save the output into ".txt" file which contains     unicodes that are outside the range of ASCII character, it gives error so can anyone help me to fix it withing the code above. What I need is to be able to save the text content into a ".txt file".

Comment: What is the error?   Where does text2 come from?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We need far more information to be able to help you.  In particular - 1. The error message that you get. 2. more code for context - what are `asksaveasfile`, `text2` and `filemenu`?  Without these things we cannot help.  It is worth checking out the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to give some guidelines on writing a good question.

Comment: asksaveasfile is from tkinter.

Comment: It gives the following error:   messagetext2save=str(text2.get(0.0,END))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)